# How to supply environments settings when using the Vercel CLI to deploy

Tags: vercel

We are using this command to promote a preview to our test environment (that has a fixed domain name):

vercel --token blah --scope blah --prod

The only issue with this is that it ends up using our production env settings on test.

We could do this, but it isn't very elegant

vercel --token blah --scope blah --prod -b key1=blah1 -b key2=blah2

Is there a way to just say what environment settings to use?

Answer (score 0):

Cutting to the chase:

```
vercel --env KEY1=value1 -e KEY2=value2 --build-env KEY1=value1 -b KEY2=value2
```

Sources are [here](https://vercel.com/docs/cli#commands/overview/unique-options/build-env) and [here](https://vercel.com/docs/cli#commands/overview/unique-options/env)

### Recommended Way

It is recommended to use the dashboard ([docs](https://vercel.com/docs/concepts/projects/environment-variables)) or `vercel env` ([docs](https://vercel.com/docs/cli#commands/env/extended-usage)) to manage your environment variables instead. That should provide you with a better experience and the newest features available.